# UK Standard visitor Visa & the brexit

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, tourist-visas

I'll admit that the subject that I'm trying to unveil might be a little bit shallow, but I hope that it'll make some sense nonetheless.

I'll be applying next year early January for the uk standard visitor Visa with an invitation from a cousin who is a legal British citizen (have incomes, a roof..etc), I am Algerian, i am a student in 3rd grade, I want to experience travelling, both of my parents are from the working class, I'll be bringing a considerably large file filled with documents of every sort (mortgage,land ownings,incomes..etc) and also some documents from my cousin that lives in the UK (child benefit, bank statements) to prove that I and him have a steady life and that I by no means intend to remain in the UK after my time of visit, that's the part that I will try by all my power to prove.

Now for the part of my question, I'm very concerned about the UK political situation in 2019 as I intended (decision made early in the summer 2018 with my cousin) to come to the UK from the 15th March to 1st April (mid term holidays) and have some time with him. now, with all the stories about how much the borders will tighten towards EU and all the scramble that will fall upon outsiders in general,I fear that my application will not be even looked at.

I'm trying hard to follow every step that the UK takes towards visas etc.. but I fear that this will be not enough and that all my effort will vanish as they'll refuse my application.

What impact will Brexit have on standard visitor visas?

Comment: [Why worry about things you cannot control and which you cannot plan for?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epictetus) - Epictetus of Hierapolis.

Comment: I've edited out the appeal to opinion and voted to reopen this question.  Surely there will be more people coming here with the same question, and we have two good fact-based answers.  We shouldn't lead people to discount those answers because the question is "on hold"  or "closed."

Answer (score 8):

Brexit has nothing to do with standard visitor visas. Whether it happens, or whenever it happens, does not make any difference for a standard visitor visa applicant.

> now, with all the stories about how much the borders will tighten towards EU and all the scramble that will fall upon outsiders in general

As long as those future visitors are legally travelling between the two zones, nothing is going to fall upon them.

> if you have concrete facts, please feel free to share them.

Even Brexit itself is not a *concrete fact* as of now. I would try this one on Politics.SE.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of getting the Visa brexit will not directly affect the policy for Visas given to non-EU nationals. It wouldn't suprise me if extra work as a result of brexit results in delays but I don't see how it would result in a rejection (of course they may still reject your Visa for other reasons).

My bigger worry would be you have planned to end your trip the day after brexit is supposed to hit. While it is hoped that even in the event of a no-deal an arrangement will be made to allow the planes to keep flying, nothing can be gauranteed with the current politial mess in the UK. If you must travel on those dates I would say your safest option is to book a flight on a carrier that is not based in the EU or UK and that does not involve any layovers in (non-UK) EU countries.